# Security for portable disk drive

Tags: security, portable-harddrive

What's the best approach for securing portable harddrives?
I have a Segate portable drive and I want to secure it incase I lose it.
Any software solutions for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just use Bitlocker its supported by Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

Comment: It's only available on ultimate edition. I have professional edition and cost around $130 to upgrade.  No other way to get it on the pro version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is the way to go. its Free, portable, and standards-compliant, so you can get to your volume whether on windows, *nix, or Mac. it stands alone, so no worries about losing certificates when your desktop drive crashes, minimizing the risk of losing access, and can be moved from drive to drive with little impact.

Comment: The only possible caveat might be that admin access is *required* on every machine one wants to use TC on to access the drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use Truecrypt, or you find it to be to complicated, you can also use a compressed zipped folder with a password. This is not as good of a method as TrueCrypt, but works as well.